# How to move the ignored files too in a checkout?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-checkout

I am working on a branch. There are some ignored files like for example config files and installed composer/bower packages.

If I checkout to an another branch, the ignored files are still there.

I would like to remove them if I check out an other branch, but I would like to get them back, if I checkout the old branch again, to continue the work on it.

How is it possible?

---

The installed composer packages are not part of the repo, only the `composer.json`, which defines the dependencies. I do not want to reinstall the packages every time I checkout the branch

The `.env` is also not part of the repo. It contains the database location, username and password. Which is different on each development environment.

Comment: add them to the repo? your question is confusing

Comment: git clean -xfd will remove all files and directories that aren't part of the repo/branch but then you won't get them back again when you check that branch out again. The only way to keep the files is to make them part of the repo.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `git stash --include-untracked`. This will create a stash with all the ignored files and then clean them up.

To recover them do: `git stash pop`. (This will remove the stashed state form the stash list).

If you want to keep the stashed state on the stash list, you can use: `git stash apply`

For more complete information about the command check [git-stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)